# Have find my iphone istalled in ipad and it's working, can't log into icloud

Tags: iphone, ipad, icloud

my ipad was recently stolen, I setup find my Iphone app and have it activated, but when I try to log into Icloud it tells me I have to setup a device with that account. If I have log into itunes and have activated the find my iphone app, doesnt that mean I have activated a device with that id?? If any could help I'd appreciate it.

Comment: are you certain you are logging into the same iCloud account that you used to set up your iPad?

Comment: Well it's the only one I can remember, I remember I set up and icloud account, but there's no way to recover that email address.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe someone steal your iPhone and disable wifi and gps, and also cancel your Apple ID(you know this days hacking iPhone password is very easy. Are you sure you set up "find my iPhone" on your device but not "find my friends"?